# What points in the unit ball sum to $a\in \mathbb{C}$?

Tags: geometry, reference-request, simplex

Write the closed complex unit ball at $0$ as $B$ and fix $a\in\mathbb{C}$, $S\! :=\! \left\lbrace z\in B^n\! : \textstyle\sum_1^n z_i = a\right\rbrace \subset \mathbb{C}^n .$
In general, what formula maps an uncomplicated domain into (at least most of) $S$?

Comment: Does the $n$ in $B^n$ in the definition of $S$ have any meaning or is it a mistake?

Comment: $z$ is an $n$-vector with components from the ball $B$, and the sum of $z$'s components equals $a$.

Comment: To clarify, if this were a question about real variables, are you asking: If $n$ is a positive integer and $a$ is a real number with $|a| < n$, describe set the of points $(x_{i})_{i=1}^n$ in the cube $[-1, 1]^n$ such that $\sum_i x_i = a$?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Yes, that's analogous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The domain is straightforward but does not admit a convenient declarative description.

Any $z\in S$ is an outcome of the following construction up to permutation of indices: For $k$ starting from $1$ and through $n$, generate $z_k$ so that $|a-\sum_{t=1}^k z_t|\leq n-k.$